# If I have multiple apps accessing the internet through one ActiveX EXE will just the ActiveX need Firewall persmission?

Tags: vb6, firewall, activex-exe

Here's one for a firewall expert:

If I have an ActiveX EXE (created in VB6) and use that for several other VB6 apps to access the internet, will I need to only get permission from the Firewall (if it blocks the access) for **just the ActiveX EXE**, or for *each* app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firewall exception will have to be created for the application that initiates the internet connection. Since in your scenario this is your ActiveX EXE process, you will need to create an exception only for it.